# How can I split a 2d matriz in x blocks in C?

Tags: c

If I want to split a matrix mat[h][w] ​​across multiple chunks as follows: each chunk must contain 5 rows and 2 columns of the matrix. Where for example: h=15 and w=8. How can I do that?

Like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilHLl.png)

Comment: Hi Diana, welcome to StackOverflow. It mentions that some matrix needs to be split, but is it meant to be stored and accessed on different memory chunks? And what is meant by splitable into columns but not in rows and columns when ultimately rows have contiguous addresses following last column from its previous one?
Please add more details in your question and clarify your desired split to expect faster resolutions.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: Do you want to **copy** the original array into 12 smaller ones? Do you want to **access** the original array elements as if they're part of a 4 dimension array (`foo[chunk_row][chunk_col][inner_row][inner_col]`)? ...

Comment: Yes, is that I want to do.

Comment: I wanna copy the otiginal array into smaller ones

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.... We don't write code for you. We can help with problems in **your** code. So post your code and tell what kind of problems you have....

Comment: yes, I think this can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Basic memory model is generally just an addressable array of bytes; how you think of this array is the important part. Is the memory increasing in number on the diagram? Are you given the output arrays? What if the numbers are not divisible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.